# S3 and .net Amazon SDK - can't download file

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I try to download file:

```
GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest
{
   BucketName = "bucket",
   Key = "file.txt"
};

var client = new AmazonS3Client("test", "test", Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);

using (GetObjectResponse response = await client.GetObjectAsync(request))
{
   ...
}
```

and when doing the localhost debugging, in the line `await client.GetObjectAsync(request)` I get the **Value cannot be null Parameter name: instance** error. The credentials are fine, the bucket and the file exists.

Comment: Do you think it may be a IAM issue or bucket permissions, given that credentials are ok ?

Comment: well, my user has the AdministratorAccess, the credentials are fine